List View with onTapGesture and onMove in SwiftUI for a macOS app
I'm noticing some weird issues/glitches with the List View when trying to add click and/or reordering.
For example, let's assume the following sample code:
List(selection: $selectedItem){
    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
        Text(item.name)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .contentShape(Rectangle()) //<-- content shape
            .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
                 print("double-clicked on item")
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                 print("clicked on item")
            }
        }.onMove { from, to in
            print("moving from \(from) to \(to)")
            items.move(fromOffsets: from, toOffset: to)
        }
    }
}

If it click anywhere inside the content shape, it works, however if I remove it, it only works when I click on the letters.
The reordering works only when .onTapGesture doesn't trigger, so if I have the . contentShape(Rectangle()) , I have to find the minuscule paddings and click and drag on those for it to trigger, but if I remove the background it works pretty much everywhere, except when I click directly on the letters of the Text()
If I completely remove the .onTapGesture reordering works as expected, so, I can drag and drop regardless of background, which I guess kinda makes sense, since onTap is hierarchically above dragging...?
My question is, is there a simpler way to have both click actions and reordering in a list?
Do I need perhaps to create a custom gesture handler?

For anyone stumbling here, I did find a solution using NSViews by merging this and this answers to similar questions, but I am still wondering whether there is a more "swiftui"-like solution.

You need to set contentShape on the frame to make it fully tappable:
Text(item)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
    .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
        print("double-clicked on item")
    }
    .onTapGesture {
        print("clicked on item")
    }

List does a lot of stuff under the hood so most likely there's some kind of Stack which by default only does hit testing on actual elements, not empty space.

.contentShape(Rectangle()) is the same as having a background color, my issue is that if I click on locations where the tap gestures register, on move does not and vice-versa. I have edited my answer to reflect that.
